# Interfacing CT sensor to Microcontroller ADC

Tags: microcontroller, sensor

I am trying to connect a Split Core current transformer(CT sensor) to my microcontroller. My CT sensor gives an AC voltage as output so i cant directly connect the output of CT to microcontroller because microcontroller should not be given AC voltage as input. Range of my CT sensor is for 0-30A detection it will give my 0-1V as output. Since the Output voltage is very low i used an Op-Amp to amplify the AC voltage and i am using LM324. By giving 9V and ground to LM324 i am able to amplify 100 mV AC to 3V AC but after this i am unable to convert this AC voltage to DC voltage. Voltage drop of diode is hindering me and the second thing is that my half wave full wave rectifier circuit is not giving me any DC output voltage. I am using multimeter for measuring voltage since i dont have an oscilloscope for measuring. I have used non inverting amplifier circuit and connected 1Kohm to inverting input of Opamp and 100kohm as feedback to inverting input. The CT sensor input is connected to non inverting input of Opamp. Any suggestions and help to achieve my output?

Comment: Is my amplification process correct? My gain is 101 and is it advised to have this much gain in op-amp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The CT sensor input is connected to non inverting input of Opamp.

You also say that the op-amp (LM324) is supplied with 9V and 0V. This is a problem. The CT output will swing positively and negatively with respect to its other terminal and, because one terminal is grounded the other terminal will raise and lower the non-inverting input of the LM324 with respect to ground. Absolute minimum voltage to be applied to an LM324 is -0.3 volts and you will exceed this limit undoubtedly.

The input common mode range is also specified down to 0V so here is a less-fatal but nonetheless significant problem. The output I would imagine will look like a half wave rectified AC power signal if the chip has survived the negative excursions.

You need to bias the CT output to some mid-rail value just as you would a microprocessor input should it be fed an AC voltage. You can do this with a capacitor and potential divider.

Also, I think, by the sound of it, you are trying to implement a rectifier in hardware - this won't work because of the tiny sizes of the signal. Try looking up "op-amp precision rectifier". You might find a circuit like this: -

[image]

Taken from [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84033/precise-full-wave-rectification) stack exchange page.

Comment: Thank you Andy for your response. I just tried the above circuit and i got 14mV DC as output. I didnt have 10k and 20k so i used 22k and 8.2k. Because of this resister value variation am i getting this low value? Any ways to increase this 14mV to atlease 200mV or higher than that? Thank you in advance and awaiting for your reply.

Comment: If you increase R5, the gain of the final op-amp increases. At the moment it is 20k and increasing it to 200k gives a x10 rise in amplitude. Alternatively reducing R4 to 2k AND reducing R3 to 1k does the same job.

Comment: Thank you andy. I tried varying the resister values but if i increase R5 value i am not getting amplified output but if i decrease it to 1K i am getting 36mV. Tried few trial and error method by varying R3 R4 and R5 and if all 3 are 1K then i am able to amplify till 150mV. Will conform you and post the result after 2 days. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The circuit shown assumes you use split rails for the op-amps or a mid-rail generator if on a single supply.

Comment: Hi Andy, no i am neither using split rail nor mid rail generator. I am directly connecting 9V and Gnd. I will try mid rail and instead of 1n4148 diode i have planned to use schottky diode to decrease voltage drop. Once i implement it i will let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADC input for AC current. You must set a sampling frequency higher then the input. I would sample x20 times to get a decent accuracy. Keep in mind the ADC reads only positive amplitude. The negative is interpreted as 0. In the program you do the averaging of multiple cycles. Try to select 12bit ADC resolution for MCU. That gives you 4095 values between 0-5v or 0-3.3v (depends on the MCU).